# JavaScript ES6 vs ES7 - what are the main differences?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, primefaces-7.0

Can anyone tell me the main differences between these two versions of JavaScript - ES6 and ES7?

Also please tell any depreciation happened between them, new modules, new concepts, other *major* differences.

Any important moments that really matter are welcomed.

Comment: there's many resources to *research* if you just look for the exact title of your question - note: es7 is old now ... I think we're up to es13 (ES2022) if not ES14 (ES2023) - did you need someone to research those (and ES8,9,10,11,12) for you as well?

Comment: Going further up, those interested in features of futures specs of JS can visit the https://tc39.es/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES7 is a smaller update compared to ES6, and it doesn't introduce as many new features. Some key additions include:

Exponentiation Operator:
The exponentiation operator (**) was introduced for easier calculation of exponentials.
Array.prototype.includes:
The includes method was added to arrays for a simpler way to check if an array includes a certain element.

Major ECMAScript versions like ES6 and ES7 aim to enhance and extend the language rather than deprecate existing features.